# Data storage optimisation

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, web

I have a form with a table where new rows can be added/deleted dynamically by clicking on add/remove button.

My problem begin when I try to save the new added/removed rows back into the database. I managed to use jQuery's Ajax to save the data, so I'm not using post var and I'm "harvesting" all the data on each input. I managed to take all these data and send them to my store.php which is storing them.

My question is, how can I save my changes with really few query, I mean, this is the output of what the store.php is sending to my mysql server:

```
UPDATE transport SET transporttype = "3" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transporttype = "2" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transporttype = "1" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportmandataire = "1" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportmandataire = "3" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportmandataire = "3" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportexpediteur = "1" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportexpediteur = "3" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportexpediteur = "3" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportdestinataire = "1" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportdestinataire = "2" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportdestinataire = "4" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transporttransporteur = "5" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transporttransporteur = "4" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transporttransporteur = "3" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportbondetransportnumerodesuivi = "1563123" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportbondetransportnumerodesuivi = "23544" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportbondetransportnumerodesuivi = "23544" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportlivraisonprevisiondate = "1" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportlivraisonprevisiondate = "1" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportlivraisonprevisiondate = "1" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportlivraisonconstatdate = "test" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportlivraisonconstatdate = "test" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportlivraisonconstatdate = "test" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportlivraisonconstatheure = "test" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportlivraisonconstatheure = "test" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportlivraisonconstatheure = "test" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportlivraisonprevisiondate = "1" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportlivraisonprevisiondate = "1" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportlivraisonprevisiondate = "1" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportlivraisonprevisionheure = "1" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportlivraisonprevisionheure = "1" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportlivraisonprevisionheure = "1" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportetat = "6" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportetat = "1" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportetat = "6" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportimperatif = "09/17/2012" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportimperatif = "09/18/2012" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportimperatif = "09/09/2012" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportbondetransportmoyendetransmission = "2" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportbondetransportmoyendetransmission = "2" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportbondetransportmoyendetransmission = "1" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportbondetransportassurance = "86" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportbondetransportassurance = "86" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportbondetransportassurance = "86" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportobservation = "Aucune observation disponible." WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportobservation = "Aucune observation disponible." WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportobservation = "Aucune observation disponible." WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationmotif = "3" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationmotif = "4" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationmotif = "1" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationnumerosuivis = "B87GT9" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationnumerosuivis = "656786" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationnumerosuivis = "C89GF8" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationdate = "09/17/2012" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationdate = "09/10/2012" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationdate = "09/24/2012" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportreclameetat = "2" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportreclameetat = "1" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportreclameetat = "1" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationrelancedate = "09/19/2012" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationrelancedate = "09/04/2012" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationrelancedate = "09/17/2012" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationrelancemoyen = "1" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationrelancemoyen = "1" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationrelancemoyen = "1" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportindemnisationdate = "09/06/2012" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportindemnisationdate = "09/19/2012" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportindemnisationdate = "09/11/2012" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportindemnisationmontant = "600" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportindemnisationmontant = "600 €" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportindemnisationmontant = "600" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportindemnisationmoyen = "1" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportindemnisationmoyen = "1" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportindemnisationmoyen = "1" WHERE id = 7
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationobservation = "Non pas d'observation" WHERE id = 1
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationobservation = "non plus" WHERE id = 6
UPDATE transport SET transportreclamationobservation = "encore moins" WHERE id = 7
```

No need to tell you this is slow as hell, something like 5 sec to store all data one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO table (id,Col1,Col2) VALUES (1,1,1),(2,2,3),(3,9,3),(4,10,12)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Col1=VALUES(Col1),Col2=VALUES(Col2);
```

Small summary of what it does:

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an
>   UPDATE of the old row is performed.

If you're running these queries from a PHP script, you should make sure that you're using prepared statements (mysqli or PDO). If you're using the regular  mysql extension, you'll be making a round-trip to the database server with each query. However, with prepared statements, you can group similar queries into one prepared statement and execute it multiple times with different data.

Comment: you mean i can prepare the query one time, then execute with each time different vars ? is it really faster ?

Comment: If you prepare an SQL statement, the database server will cache the query, allowing you to execute it multiple times with different data. For example, you'll create a prepared statement for the first 6 queries and execute it 6 times. Then you'll create another prepared statement for the 6 queries that come after and so on.

Comment: Still a problem, i can't use prepared statement when the Table name is never the same, any hint ?

Comment: Group the queries that are the same up into prepared statements. Example: The transporttype would have it's own prepared statement and you'd execute that statement three times with different data: UPDATE transport SET transporttype = :transporttype WHERE id = :id